# Using a NodeJS 4 script from Python on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda

### The problem

- I have a Python script running on AWS Lambda.
- This script is using `subprocess` to execute a NodeJS 4 script.

### What have I tried

- `subprocess.check_output('my-script.js');`
- Got a non-zero result
- Got the interpreter error:

  Version of node.js doesn't meet minimum requirement.
  Please ensure system has node.js version 4.0.0 or higher.
- `subprocess.check_output('node -v');` printed it's 0.10.x

### My question

Is it possible to use a NodeJS 4 script from a Python AWS Lambda?

Comment: I have read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) and it's quite confuse, I'm not sure if node.js enviroment is installed in a Python container...Have you try to execute the command "nodejs --version" or "node --version" to make sure you have the environment to execute a js script?

Comment: @TomMelo Yeah, I did. Just forgot to mention in my question. It's 0.10.x

Comment: Why not just use a NodeJS lambda then?

Comment: @dashmug The code is already written in Python. It would time to translate.

Comment: It's weird that 0.10 exists on the python runtime. That should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on `node` existing on the Lambda `python` runtimes. AWS might remove or change it any time.

It would be best if you just translate them into one language so you only need one runtime. Either translate the node script into python or translate the python script to node.

If translation is not feasible, you can create two Lambda functions -- one in Python and one in Node. You can then have the Python Lambda invoke the Node Lambda using [`.invoke()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke)

Comment: I ended up with two Lambdas. It was the more cost-effective solution in my case.