# How to run a Python script from a Node.js AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda

### Running non Node.js executables from a Node.js Lambda Function is possible as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/).

Having a Node.js Lambda Function I want to run a Python script using Node.js' *child_process* command.

I followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/) AWS tutorial and included the following at the start of my .js function:

```
process.env[‘PATH’] = process.env[‘PATH’] + ‘:’ + process.env[‘LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT’];
```

And the main Python script call starts here:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

function calculateSomething(next) {
  var script = spawn('python', ['my_python_script.py', args]);

  script.stdout.on('data', (data) => { doSomething(data); });
  script.on('error', (error) => { console.error(error); });
  script.on('exit', () => { next(); });
}
```

The Python script runs using an external library (e.g., numpy), so I have to install it using pip.

Now:

- What do I have to do for installing pip libraries inside a Node.js Lambda?
- Is it enough for linking my Python script with Node.js Function to add this `process.env[‘PATH’] = process.env[‘PATH’] + ‘:’ + process.env[‘LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT’];` at the start of my .js function?

It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716105/using-a-nodejs-4-script-from-python-on-aws-lambda) other question.

Comment: You can invoke another python based lambda function from node.js lambda function?

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi I'll prefer to not create another Lambda if it's possible and run the Python script on the same Function. BTW, if that solution makes it run faster I'll consider that. Thank you!

Comment: Well, a deep read in AWS FAQs is saying that, indeed, it's possible:

Q: Can I execute other programs from within my AWS Lambda function written in Node.js?

Yes. Lambda’s built-in sandbox lets you run batch (“shell”) scripts, other language runtimes, utility routines, and executables.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: I think the fact that python is available is only due to having a common Amazon Linux baseline. If you try finding "node" in a python runtime lambda, it won't be there (tested on python 3.7)

Comment: Just tested on node JS 12 runtime and it seems they now removed python, this fails `spawn('python', ['--version']);` with `Error: spawn python ENOENT`. The article only mentions running other executables but both runtime and exec are for node.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [custom runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html) to run multiple languages